# Gridview column linkbutton change the value according to data

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to complete a simple task; 
a `gridview column` gets an integer data if integer is equals to zero print "active" and set the `commandname` of the linkbutton to active else set linkbutton text  and command value to inactive.

here is what I have so far

```
<Columns>
   <asp:BoundField HeaderText = "User Name" DataField="UserName" 
                   HeaderStyle-Width="16%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"  />
   <asp:BoundField HeaderText = "Role" DataField="RoleNAME" 
                   HeaderStyle-Width="14%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"  />
   <asp:BoundField HeaderText = "Group" DataField="GroupName" 
                   HeaderStyle-Width="12%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"  />
   <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="link" CommandName = "Active" 
                    HeaderText="Status" Text="Active" 
                    HeaderStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"  />
   <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="link" CommandName = "Edit" 
                    HeaderText="" Text="Edit/View" 
                    HeaderStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"  />
</Columns>
```

codebehind

```
protected void grdMyQueue_RowdataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // In template column,
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var obj = (User)e.Row.DataItem;
        if (obj.isDisabled == 0)
        {
            LinkButton linkButton = new LinkButton();
            linkButton.Text = "Active";  
            linkButton.Enabled = true;
            linkButton.CommandName = "Active";
            //linkButton.CommandArgument = e.Row. //this might be causing the problem 
            e.Row.Cells[3].Controls.Clear();
            e.Row.Cells[3].Controls.Add(linkButton);
        }
        else
        {
            LinkButton linkButton = new LinkButton();
            linkButton.Text = "InActive"; 
            linkButton.Enabled = true;
            linkButton.CommandName = "InActive";
            e.Row.Cells[3].Controls.Add(linkButton);

        }

    }
}
```

However when I Click the active linkbutton on the cell I get an error at `onrowcommand` function

```
protected void OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument); // this is the error line 
    GridViewRow gvRow = userManager.Rows[index];
    TableCell usrName = gvRow.Cells[0];
    string userName = usrName.Text;
....
```

How can I manage to change `LinkButton` text and `CommandName` depending on that integer data?

P.S I tried `Eval` but I couldnt figure out whats going on....

Comment: `linkButton.CommandArgument = e.Row.RowIndex.ToString();` this solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I would simply return the data from your data source, as intended.  Then I would use an `Update Panel` to avoid the `Postback` that will occur from your `Link Button`.  As for the text modifying I would use Javascript, so Javascript will read the page on the client.  So when your data source returns:

- One
- One
- Two
- One

The Javascript can analyze those rows, then modify the internal cell within the `Grid` quite painless.

An example of Javascript:

```
$(".Activator").each(function () {
     if ($(this).prev().find(':checkbox').prop('checked')) {
          $(this).text("Deactivate");
     }
});
```

This example will validate if a checkbox is checked, if it is modify the internal `text` to the class `.Activator`.

Then the internal item in the `Grid` for code on front-end would look like:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active">
     <ItemTemplate>

          <asp:CheckBox
               ID="CustomerCheck" runat="server"
               Checked='<%# Eval("Active") %>'
               Enabled="false" />

          <asp:LinkButton
               ID="lbCustomerActive" runat="server"
               Text="Activate"
               CommandName="OnActivate"
               ToolTip='<%# "Activate or Deactivate Course: " + Eval("CourseID") %>'
               OnClick="CustomerCheck_Click"
               CssClass="Activator">

         </asp:LinkButton>

     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

As you can see, as the internal data is changed the Javascript will automatically adjust the value for me every time the `Data Source` is binded again.  Which the `CustomerCheck_Click` would execute the code on the server, which will read the `Command Argument` which contains the `Row Id`.  Which will `Update` that particular record without a problem and rebind the `Grid`. (Partially lied, I'm parsing the `Tooltip`).

You would instantiate on server side like:

```
((LinkButton)sender).ToolTip;
```